# java regex negate with boundaries (square bracktes)

Tags: java, regex

I would appreciate if anybody could help me with a JAVA regex requirement
I got a String like `"/ABC/KLM[XYZ/ABC/KLM]/ABC"`

I want to replace all ABC **not** surround by square brackets.
In this case only the first and last ABC should be found. 
But not ABC in the middle because it is surrounded with square brackets

Comment: Do you have to care about nested brackets?

Comment: Will there be any random open or close bracket, or will all open brackets have a close bracket

Comment: This is an ugly problem to handle with regex alone.  You should probably use a parser.

Comment: nested brackets -->  yes, the String could also look like

"/ABC/KLM[XYZ/ABC/[XYZ/ABC/KLM]KLM]/ABC"
  or  

"/ABC/[XYZ/ABC/KLM]KLM[XYZ/ABC/KLM]/ABC"

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate what you mean with parser?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: This is an ugly problem to handle with Java regex alone. You should probably use a nicer language. :P (Ruby: `"/ABC/KLM[XYZ/ABC[DEF/ABC]/KLM]/ABC".gsub(%r{ ABC | (?<b>\[ (?:[^\]] | \g<b>)* \]) }x) { |m| m.start_with?("[") ? m : "abc" }` gives `"/abc/KLM[XYZ/ABC[DEF/ABC]/KLM]/abc"`) :P

Comment: Better you take out the string inside `[...]` and place a marker on those positions. After that check for `ABC` in remaining sting & replace it as you required. Then again replace the markers with corresponding strings which we have removed first.

Comment: Create a stack.  Everytime you see an open bracket `[` push it onto the stack.  Everytime you see a closing bracket `]` pop an open bracket from the stack.  Then, _only_ replace `ABC` when the stack is empty.

Comment: @Sinto: As I have only small  JAVA regex knowledge, I do not know how to create a marker.

Comment: You are attempting to use the wrong tool for the job.  You need a simple parser (which might use simple regexes itself) instead of one large regex.

Comment: @MarioMueller: I just meant a piece of text or something, which will help us to replace the string in `[...]` (which we taken before replacing `ABC`)

Comment: @Sinto: it's not that simple - remember, OP can have multiple sets of brackets. You'd need to replace each outermost bracket with a different marker, so you can restore them (and Java doesn't have replaceAll with expression, so it's a PITA), or look them up again in the original string (also not trivial). Tim's bracket counting state machine is definitely easiest here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without a recursive regular expression. Java does not support this within the standard libraries, but flavours of regex found in Perl or .NET do. This is in essence the same problem as trying to match content within HTML tags - by far the easiest way to do it is using a **stack-based parser**.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here:

```html
    public class MergeParentAndChildXPATH {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  
  String substringToBeFound = "ABC";
  String toReplayceWith = "XXX";
  String xPathFromExcel = "/UTILMD/ABC/[XYZ/ABC/KLM]KLM[XYZ/ABC/[XYZ/ABC/KLM]KLM]/ABC";
  System.out.println("original    String\t"+xPathFromExcel);
  String manupulatedString = mergeParentAndChildXPATH(substringToBeFound, toReplayceWith,xPathFromExcel);
  
  System.out.println("manipulated String\t"+manupulatedString);
  
  
 }

 public static String  mergeParentAndChildXPATH(String substringToBeFound, String toReplayceWith, String xPathFromExcel  ) {
  StringBuffer sbManipulatedString = new StringBuffer();
  
  int lengthABC = substringToBeFound.length();
  CharStack charStack = new CharStack();
  
  
  String substringAfterMatch = "";
  while (xPathFromExcel.indexOf(substringToBeFound)>-1) {
   int matchStartsAt = xPathFromExcel.indexOf(substringToBeFound); 
   int matchEndssAt = xPathFromExcel.indexOf(substringToBeFound)+lengthABC;
   String substringBeforeMatch = xPathFromExcel.substring(0, matchStartsAt);
   substringAfterMatch = xPathFromExcel.substring(matchStartsAt+lengthABC);
   String substringMatch = xPathFromExcel.substring(matchStartsAt, matchEndssAt);
//   System.out.println("Loop Count\t"+loopCount);
//   System.out.println("substringBeforeMatch\t"+substringBeforeMatch);
//   System.out.println("substringAfterMatch\t"+substringAfterMatch);
//   System.out.println("starts "+matchStartsAt+ " ends "+matchEndssAt);
//   System.out.println("Output of match: "+substringMatch);
   
   // now tokenize the string till match is reached and memorize brackets via Stack
   String sTokenize = xPathFromExcel;
   for (int i = 0; i < matchStartsAt; i++) {
    char ch = sTokenize.charAt(0);
//    System.out.println(ch);
//    System.out.println(sTokenize.substring(0,1));
    if (ch == '[') {
     charStack.push(ch);
    }
    if (ch == ']') {
     charStack.pop();
    }
    sTokenize = sTokenize.substring(1);
   }//for
   if (charStack.empty()) {
    
    substringMatch = substringMatch.replaceAll(substringMatch, toReplayceWith);
   }
   // 
   sbManipulatedString.append(substringBeforeMatch + substringMatch);
//   System.out.println("manipulatedString\t"+sbManipulatedString.toString());
   xPathFromExcel = substringAfterMatch;
//   System.out.println("remaining String\t"+substringAfterMatch);
   
   
  }
  return (sbManipulatedString.toString()+substringAfterMatch);

 }
}

import java.util.Stack;

public class CharStack {

 private Stack theStack;

 CharStack() {
  theStack = new Stack();
 }

 public char peek() {
  Character temp = (Character) theStack.peek();
  return temp.charValue();
 }

 public void push(char c) {
  theStack.push(new Character(c));
 }

 public char pop() {
  char temp = (Character) theStack.pop();
  return temp;
 }

 public boolean empty() {
  return theStack.empty();
 }

}
```